# How to run VS 2013 or VS 2015 as windows 8 mode?

Tags: windows-8.1, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

Is it possible to run VS 2013 or VS 2013 as windows 8 mode just like in google chrome? Something like metro UI or desktop mode. I really don't know how windows call it.

I am using windows 8.1 but will soon upgrade to windows 10.

Comment: What do you mean by "Windows 8 mode like in Chrome"?

Comment: I've edited my question by adding more information. Please check.